# Prove the following formulas(derivatives)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let be the functions $f$ and $g$ many times differentiable functions, then

(i)$(fg)'''=f'''g+3f''g'+3f'g''+fg'''$

(ii)$(fg)^{(n)}=f^{(n)}g+\binom{n}{1}f^{(n-1)}g'+\binom{n}{2}f^{(n-2)}g''+...+fg^{(n)}$

For the first formula I have tried to follow the recipe of the well known proof of

Comment: By induction like binomial formula.

Comment: This the Leibniz formula and the proof is by induction.